# How to hide specific text from search bar result?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to hide specific text from search bar result?

For example when a user search for

12345 result = Apple

How can I hide the number that contains apple from the search bar result with four stars (****) ?

12345 result= ****

The response for the search is **** rather than apple.

Also even if the number contain multiple text red apple and green apple. how can I hide every number that contain apple from the result with four stars (****), rather than showing result as green apple and red apple.

112233 result = Green apple

221133 result = Red apple

112233 result = ****

221133 result = ****

```
setState(() {
  loading = false;
  if(response["data"]==null){
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "No result found.");
    searchResult = [];
    return;
  }
  searchResult = response["data"];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `response["data"]` a string?

```
if (searchResult.includes("apple") {
 searchResult = "***";
}
```